# Extract data from tr>td for each column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that i would like to extract data from the textareas in the in the row td

see below

```
ID  | METHOD | COMPENDIA | SPECS
-----------------------------------
 1  |   ta1   |  ta2      | ta3
    ------------------------------
       ta1b   | ta2b      | ta3b
------------------------------------
```

ta - textareas, like the ones under column METHOD have the same class  method, compendia for the next column and specs fro the last column

What I would like to do is, if focusout the textarea in a given tr>td, i grab the ID of the row. When I move to the Methods column, I want to grab the value of both textareas, and when I move to the next column I want to do the same without METHOD column. The code I have grabs all columns regardless

### HTML

```
<table id="temp_table">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>METHOD</th>
        <th>SPECS</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="method">ta1</textarea>
                <textarea class="method">ta1b</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="compendia">ta2</textarea>
                <textarea class="compendia">ta2b</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="specs">ta3</textarea>
                <textarea class="specs">ta3b</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$('#temp_table tbody tr').focusout(function(){
    var data="";
    test_id =$('.test_id',this).val();
    $('.method',this).each(function(i, val){
        data+=val.value+":";
    });
    methods=data.substring(0, data.length - 1);

    $.post(base_url+'audit/getAuditDataBottom/'+labref+'/'+test_id+'/method/method',{method:methods}, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});

$('#temp_table tbody tr').focusout(function(){
    var data="";
    test_id =$('.test_id',this).val();
    $('.compendia',this).each(function(i, val){
        data+=val.value+":";
    });
    compedias=data.substring(0, data.length - 1);

    $.post(base_url+'audit/getAuditDataBottom/'+labref+'/'+test_id+'/compedia/compedia',{compedia:compedias}, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to update server if nothing was changed so I would use `change` event on the textareas

```
$('#temp_table textarea').on('change',function(e){
      var postData;

      var type = this.className, 
          $cell = $(this).parent(), 
          test_id =$cell.parent().find('.test_id',this).val(),
          data =  $cell.find('textarea').map(function(){
              return this.value;
          }).get().join(':'),
         url = base_url+'audit/getAuditDataBottom/'+labref+'/'+test_id+'/';

      switch(type){

         case 'method':
           url += 'method/method';
           postData = {method: data}
         break;
      }

     $.post(url, postData , function(response){
           console.log(response);
     });


});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use xpath

```
//tr/td/textarea[@class='method'] Selects all the title elements that have a "class" attribute with a value of "method"
//tr/td/textarea[@class='compendia']
//tr/td/textarea[@class='specs']
```

here is some tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Also you table is not right, it should be like:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <textarea class="method">ta1</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea class="compendia">ta2</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea class="specs">ta3</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
        <textarea class="method">ta1b</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea class="compendia">ta2b</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea class="specs">ta3b</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what does xpath have to do with this? OP is using jQuery